# Symfony 3 sharing cookies across sub-domains?

Tags: symfony, session, cookies, subdomain, symfony-3.3

I want to share a cookie across any subdomain. This should then allow me to keep the session. I am using the Symfony framework version 3.0.

I've read that you should set the following:

```
## app/config/config.yml
   session:
       cookie_domain: .localhost
```

I tried multiple variations on this but none of them change anything.
the domain associated with the cookie won't change. Any ideas how this should be done?? What am I missing.

Comment: The cookie won't change.
You need to delete your cookie and log back. 

I just tested it, it works fine

Comment: I deleted my cookie and now no cookie will come back but when i remove the cookie domain property i get a cookie

Comment: I found a gist where the user use thoses params, can you try? `cookie_lifetime: 0`
        `save_path: %kernel.root_dir%/var/sessions`
        `cookie_domain: .my-domain.com`
        `name: SFSESSID`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To be sure you need to delete your cookie and log back.

```
session:
    cookie_lifetime: 0
    save_path: %kernel.root_dir%/var/sessions
    cookie_domain: .my-domain.com
    name: SFSESSID
```

Comment: This works flawlessly. Please remember to remove your cookie storage before next login or you won't be able to login (with CSRF enabled). This is also a problem on already-deployed systems (you won't ask your users to clear their cookies, right?), so easiest solution is to change `session.name` parameter to other than previous (in most cases `PHPSESSID`).

Comment: Symfony 5.4 here, I had to do the same renaming thing to get login working.